# Youtube Upload Automation and Large Files

Tags: python, api, youtube, upload

I am using Python and the Youtube Data APi to write automation software to handle my broadcast companies daily youtube uploads.

Currently the program does not seem to be completing large uploads >1GB. The upload is initiated but after an hour it has yet to complete. Even if it does finish this is not an acceptable "time to upload."

Why does the upload not complete? Is there a way to hasten the upload process?
Thank you

Here is the portion of the program that handles the actual upload.

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=creds)

upload = youtube.videos().insert(  # Build Upload Call
    part="snippet,status",
    body={
        "snippet": {
            "categoryId": "27",
            "description": descName,
            "title": titleName,
            "tags": ['one','two']
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "public"
        }
    },
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(
        y, chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)
)

while upload is None:
    upload = upload.next_chunk()
    if "id" in upload:
        print('video uploaded')
    else:
        exit('a failure has occured:', upload)

videoId = json.loads(json.dumps(upload.execute())).get(
    'id')
```

I need the upload of a 1GB video to youtube to succeed within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Have you referenced [Video stuck during upload](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4525858?hl=en)? You might want to look into [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol).

Comment: I presume you've checked that you have enough bandwidth between you and youtube?  1GB per hour is ~280 KB per second, i.e. ~2.2 megabits per second

Comment: The program is designed to automate an existing workload. Videos of this size take this workstation around 20 minutes to upload when uploading manually.  This accounts for the variables suggested by the Youtube Help page you have provided. I think the issue lays in my limited understanding of the Resumable Uploads code, specifically the MediaFileUpload method. I believe implementing a Retry system as is used in the Resumable Uploads code provided by youtube, or perhaps changing my utilization of the MediaFileUpload method  will yield the results I desire. Perhaps someone can input on this?